# Nested property changed notifications for a Realm object

Tags: data-binding, xamarin.forms, realm, inotifypropertychanged, fody-propertychanged

I am using Realm and PropertyChanged Fody in my Xamarin Forms project. I have two models - `Person` and `Friend` which are like below. The `person` object has a reference to the `friend` object. I have binded the `Age` of the `person` and the `friend` to two separate labels. Now as I am using `PropertyChanged Fody`, whenever the `Age` changes it should update the labels. But only the first label (*person's Age*) updates, the second one(*person's friend's Age*) doesn't. How can I raise notifications when the age of the friend changes?

```
    [ImplementPropertyChanged]
    public class Person : RealmObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public Friend friend { get; set; }
    }

    [ImplementPropertyChanged]
    public class Friend : RealmObject
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
```

I bind them in the Xaml like below.

```
    <Label Text="{Binding person.Age}" />
    <Label Text="{Binding person.friend.Age}" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need PropertyChanged.Fody because Realm has notifications built in. My guess is it's interfering with Realm's logic because what you describe should just work.